# How to clear sfdx cache (if such thing exists)

Tags: salesforce-lightning

When I apply:

```
sfdx force:source:push -f
```

(Sorry, orginally posted wrong command)
The deployment fails because the compiler throws errors regarding files that are no longer part of my local filesystem.

I cleared following files:

- metadataTypeInfos.json
- sourcePathInfos.json

To no avail.
Is there some cache anywhere that I need to clear?

Answer (score 2):

I think something has gone wrong with the diffing mechanism. 
Deleting files / folders and meanwhile clearing sourcePathInfos.json.

Anyhow, I deleted the import to the file that was no longer needed and the problem went away with it.
It doesn't really solve the problem as sfdx still thinks that the folder exists (the logs show unresolved imports in files that no longer exist) but I don't really care about it a I'm working scratch org).

It can just be fixed by creating a new scratch org too:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a <scratch-name> -s
```